# Custom texonomy redirect on page not found

Tags: php, wordpress

```
add_action( 'init', 'products_post_product' );

function add_custom_taxonomies() {
  // Add new "Locations" taxonomy to Posts
  register_taxonomy('Categorys', 'products', array(
    // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
    'hierarchical' => true,

   'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => false,

 //   'hide_meta_box' => true, 
    // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => _x( 'categorys', 'taxonomy general name' ),
      'singular_name' => _x( 'Categorys', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
      'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Categorys' ),
      'all_items' => __( 'All Categorys' ),
      'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Categorys' ),
      'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Categorys:' ),
      'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Categorys' ),
      'update_item' => __( 'Update Categorys' ),
      'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Categorys' ),
      'new_item_name' => __( 'New Categorys Name' ),
      'menu_name' => __( 'Categorys' ),
    ),
    // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'categorys', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
     // 'with_front' => true, // Don't display the category base before "/locations/"
     // 'hierarchical' => false // This will allow URL's like "/locations/boston/cambridge/"
    ),
  )
);

}
```

Above is my code : But my taxonomy term page is redirecting to page not found page.  My url hhtp://url.com/categorys- 404 page .Am I making any mistake in code or I have to redirect the page to other page or I have to create other page my my taxonomy slug .Need Help

Comment: try with some different name for `slug` just for testing rename `'slug' => 'categorys'` to `'slug' => 'my-text'`. and try to access the url http://url.com/my-text and see if it is working.

Comment: I have tried this also but all in vain .. nothing is working

Comment: You have initialized `products_post_product` but your method name is `add_custom_taxonomies`. So rename name any one of them. I think this might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Above is my code : But my taxonomy term page is redirecting to page not found page. My url hhtp://url.com/categorys- 404 page .Am I making any mistake in code or I have to redirect the page to other page or I have to create other page my my taxonomy slug .Need Help

Ans :  Required to create file for your taxonomy e.g. taxonomy-categorys.php
as your taxonomy name with before taxonomy word

Comment: I have created that file  but that files run on  hhtp://url.com/categorys/post1 .Its not running for taxonomy term-  hhtp://url.com/categorys

Comment: add_action( 'init', 'products_post_product' );
function add_custom_taxonomies() {
...
}

Please change action as function name as below

add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies' );
function add_custom_taxonomies() {
...
}